# Matrix representation for a isomorphism $V \to V^\ast$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a vector space with basis $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ and we have an isomorphism $L :V \to V^\ast$ where $V^\ast$ is the dual space what is the matrix representation for $L$?

I'm slightly confused about this as I'm not sure what basis $V^\ast$ has. On one hand it's the basis uniquely determined by taking the elements $\{\varphi_1, \dots, \varphi_n\}$ such that $\varphi_i(v_j) = \delta_i^j$, but on the other hand since $L$ is an isomorphism the basis would be $\{L(v_1), \dots, L(v_n)\}$.

Any help to sort out my confusion would be helpful here.

Comment: It's not known a priori. If it was given like that the two would coincide right? @Surb

Comment: The matrix $[L_{ij}]$ is defined by $L(v_j)=\sum L_{ij}v_i^\ast$. If we apply both sides to $v_i$, we get $L_{ij}=L(v_j)(v_i)$.

Comment: @elemelons Thanks. I think you could write this as an answer in order for future reference for other people.